# Replace semicolon with hash on a line in a file using java/groovy

Tags: java, groovy

I have a file with the following contents

```
PackId1;ChannelId1;SalesCode1;AccountNumber1
PackId2;ChannelId2;SalesCode2;AccountNumber2
PackId3;ChannelId3;SalesCode3;AccountNumber3
PackId4;ChannelId4;SalesCode4;AccountNumber4
.
.
.
.
.
PackId10;ChannelId10;SalesCode10;AccountNumber10
```

I wrote code to read the first line of the above file. Now, after the line is read i want to replace all the semicolon(;) to hash(#) or some other special character so that next time the same line is not read.

Please help me in replacing the string (;) to (#) using java/groovy.

Tried `replaceFirst()` as below, but it didn't work for me

```
   str = str.replaceFirst("\\\;" , "\\\\#")
```

Comment: I tried the below code with replace():- def myFile = new File("C:/Users/Desktop/Cont.txt") 
def fileText = myFile.text
str=fileText.split('\n')
str=str.replace(';','#')

It's throwing error "groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: [Ljava.lang.String;.replace() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [;, #] Possible solutions: reverse() error at line: 4"

Comment: Or is there any way to remove the first line of a file once its is read using groovy?
Initially file contents:
PackId1;ChannelId1;SalesCode1;AccountNumber1
PackId2;ChannelId2;SalesCode2;AccountNumber2
PackId3;ChannelId3;SalesCode3;AccountNumber3
.
.
.
.
.

after reading the first line

file contents should be

PackId2;ChannelId2;SalesCode2;AccountNumber2
PackId3;ChannelId3;SalesCode3;AccountNumber3
.
.
.
.
.

new File("C:/Users/Desktop/Cont.txt").withReader { reader ->
  while (reader.readLine() != null) {

     str1 = reader.readLine()

above code reads the first line of a file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use regexes here, like [`replaceFirst()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) does. Use [`replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) instead:

```
str = str.replace(";" , "#")
```

Answer (score 2):

What didn't work?

```
 'PackId1;ChannelId1;SalesCode1;AccountNumber1 PackId2;ChannelId2;SalesCode2;AccountNumber2'.replace(';','#')
```